# Cyrillic characters in MessageBox class of Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, localization, sencha-touch

I am working with different languages with the Sencha Touch framework, and translating MessageBox buttons to different languages, I have added it and it is working but with the russian I am having problems, instead of appears the correct translation appears "???" doesn´t detect correctly the translation with special characters. Any clue?

Comment: Make sure that your JavaScript files are in UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I am working with UTF8 charset, but I have solved this issue receiving the labels from the backend here the code:

```
 var language = 'RU', //sent from the backend
            overWriting = Ext.MessageBox.YESNO;
        switch (language) {
            case "RU" :
                var b = Ext.MessageBox;

                Ext.apply(b, {
                    YES: {text: 'russian text YES', itemId: 'yes', ui: 'action'},
                    NO: {text:'russian text NO', itemId: 'no'}
                });

                Ext.apply(b, {
                    YESNO: [b.NO, b.YES]
                });
                overWriting = b.YESNO;
                break;
}
```